# Не подключается файл стилей в документ HTML

Tags: javascript, css

Вопрос наверное банальный, но мучаюсь и не могу решить. Решил поиграться со стилями и в файл `index.html` добавил стиль `changed.css` который просто меняет цвет на красный левого блока `nav` Если его `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="changed.css">` прописывать вручную под `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`
все отлично срабатывает и цвет блока становится красным вместо серого(он задан в `style.css` ), если выше - то нет. Так и должно быть это логично.
Но если создавать `link` через `js`

```
var f = document;
var head = f.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link = f.createElement('link');
link.type = 'text/ccs';
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = 'changed.css';
head.appendChild(link);
```

в коде он появляется, в отладчике я его вижу и отображается ниже, но вот свойства не схватываются, блок все равно серый, как прописано в style.css
В чем может быть причина, Кэш и куки я почистил, все равно не работает.

Comment: a если в `changed.css` задать стиль, который больше нигде не определен, будет работать?

Comment: сделать `grey.css` и `red.css`, и не подключать вместе, заменять один другим

Answer (score 0):

В одной буковке ошибся `link.type = 'text/css';`,  А НЕ `link.type = 'text/ccs';`